# filter rows on match in rownames

Tags: r

I am trying to remove all rows that do not have 0 in the third part of the rowname. Why is my code not working?

```
idx <- which(read.table(text=rownames(miraligner_Nov_s2))$V3=="0")
miraligner_Nov_s2MM <- miraligner_Nov_s2[-idx] 

> head(miraligner_Nov_s2)
                                                      freq
hsa-miR-183-5p TATTGCACTGGTAGAATTCACTGAA 4TG I-AA 0 G    1
hsa-miR-21-3p CAACACCAGTCGATGGGCTGAT 0 I-AT 0 t          1
hsa-miR-22-3p AAGCTGACAGTTGAAGAACTGA 7AC I-A 0 t         5
hsa-miR-769-5p TGAGACCTCTGGGTTCCGAGCT 17CT 0 0 0         1
hsa-miR-429 TAATACTGTCGGGTAAAACCGT 11GT 0 0 0            1
hsa-miR-148b-5p GAGTTCTGTTATACACTCAGGCT 1GA 0 0 T        1
```

Comment: Probably use `grepl` or `grep`. ``df[!grepl("0", fixed=TRUE, row.names(df)),]`` or `df[grep("0", fixed=TRUE, row.names(df), invert=TRUE),]` should work.

Comment: how do you specify the third part of the rowname?

Comment: The "third part" is a bit vague. Maybe the regex "[^ ]+ [^ ]+ 0". and drop fixed=TRUE, so `df[!grepl("^[^ ]+ [^ ]+ 0", row.names(df)),]` if 0 occurs immediately after the second space. Beyond this, you'll have to spend more time in your Q specifying what you mean by "third part" as it is not immediately clear.

Comment: the row names are spece separated. So I mean the part between space 2 and 3

Comment: Then that regex in my second comment should work.

Comment: Thanks. Worked great

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
miraligner_Nov_s2 %>% rownames_to_column() %>% separate(col=rowname, sep = " ", into=paste0("col", as.character(1:6))) %>% filter(col3 != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in the comments, the third part of the row name concerns the third block of text separated by spaces. In this case, the regex "[^ ]+ [^ ]+ 0" should work. So

```
df[!grepl("^[^ ]+ [^ ]+ 0", row.names(df)),]
```

will return the data.frame where 0 occurs immediately after the second space. Similarly, you could use `grep` like

```
df[grep("^[^ ]+ [^ ]+ 0", row.names(df), invert=TRUE),]
```

which will return the same result.

Other regex variations

- "^\\S+\\s\\S+\\s0"
- "^\\S+ \\S+ 0"

Comment: Got a problem now hat the ouput is not a data frame and do not contain rownames. Only the second columns with values is output.

Comment: Please clarify. Is your data different from the data in the example? If the information is stored in a variable, use `df$varname` in place of `row.names(df)` with proper substitution.

Comment: no, it is stored in the row names so that is strange. it is also a data frame

Comment: The rows are correlctly identified buy the subsetting is not working for some reason: head(grep("^[^ ]+ [^ ]+ 0", row.names(miraligner_28Nov_s1), invert=TRUE))
[1]  3  4  5  7  9 10